# How to track utm_source,utm_medium in google analytics Android SDK?

Tags: android, eclipse, email, google-analytics

I am trying to track emailIDs of the user who is using my application. For all the events I am using Google Analytics.

Now, I want to set source as the email id of the person who logged into my application.

How to do that?

For all the events & page views that were tracked till now,

**Source** is **direct**

**Medium** is **None**

I even tried with **setReferrer** . Even then, if I search for **ReferralPath** as secondary dimension but the value is **(not set)**

Please advice me, what is the best way to track email address? Or how to set **Souce** as email address?

Comment: what version of analytics that you are using? if you are using the v3, you can find a examples on this page https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/campaigns?hl=pt-BR

Comment: I am using v2. Can't I do in v2?

Answer (score 0):

you can do using the v2 too. In this link you will find tutorials:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns

if you use the EasyTracker, you can use (not tested):

```
String campaign = "campaign_parameters_like_this:utm_campaign=my_campaign&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=my_keyword&utm_content=ad_variation1";
EasyTracker.getTracker().setCampaign(campaign);
```

to set a default general campaign.